# check Object type from String

Tags: java, xml

I'm extracting value from XML and trying to convert it to an appropriate Object... Lets say, value can be numeric/boolean/String.
as an example...

```
<value> 123 </value>
<value> TRUE </value>
<value> some Strings </value>
```

I'm reading the value from XML as String. Any idea what would be the best approach to convert the String to the appropriate java Object? (ie. BigDecimal/Boolean/String) 
This is what I'm thinking as a solution:

```
    private Object convertParameterValIntoObject(String value){

    Object toreturn = null;
    BigDecimal numeric = null;
    Boolean boo = null;

    try{        
        //deal with numeric val
        numeric = new BigDecimal(value.trim());
        return numeric;         
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        try{
            //deal with Boolean
            if(value.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("true") || 
                    value.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("false")){

                boo = new Boolean(value.trim());
                return boo;
            }
            else throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception e1) {

            // String 
            return value.trim();
        }
    }       
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Hasan.

Comment: Well this seems ok to me. Are you encountering any error?

Comment: I don't get any error. It works fine. But, looking for better solution (If any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use java.util.Scanner which has all the type detection you need. Here's a working example. You need to make sure you probe the type from the most specific to the least specific, here I test for boolean, then number, then string.

```
String[] testValues = { "123", "123.4", "FALSE", "false",
        "some strings" };

for (String test : testValues) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(test);
    scanner.useDelimiter("^");
    if (scanner.hasNextBoolean()) {
        boolean value = scanner.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println("boolean " + value);
    } else if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        double value = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("number " + value);
    } else if (scanner.hasNext(".*")) {
        String value = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("string " + value);
    }
}
```

Output

```
number 123.0
number 123.4
boolean false
boolean false
string some strings
```

Answer (score 2):

Solving this problem without supplying more information would result in a bad solution.

I highly recommend supplying an [XSD](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp) for your XML, the XSD contains meta data about your XML including the data type. Once the XSD is available you have many options for converting the XML to a Java Object (I recommend [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html))

Using JAXB you can generate the Java Objects from the XSD, or write the Objects yourself and use JAXB annotations to supply some meta data.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)? In your case it will be very simple: (below a quote from XStream 2 minutes tutorial)

To construct an object, purely from the XML:

```
Person newJoe = (Person)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

And that's how simple XStream is!